# Get the last 30 minutes from a log file

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a log file, and I want to retreive only the last 30 minutes of logs on that file using powershell scripting.

```
23:59:58 02/01/2020 multiple fields
23:59:58 02/01/2020 multiple fields
23:59:58 02/01/2020 multiple fields
23:59:58 02/01/2020 multiple fields
```

I know that I can get de date using

```
$Date = Get-Date
```

this is the format that returns

```
lunes, 24 de febrero de 2020 10:30:38
```

how can I use this to retrieve only the logs from the las 30 minutes?-

Comment: Can we assume that the lines in the file are always in chronological order (oldest to newest)?

Comment: Yes they are in order (oldest to newest) but some logs can have the same timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no order, you can do the following assuming your logs are in `log.log`:

```
$TargetTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)
switch -File log.log {
    { [datetime]($_ -replace "(^\S+\s\S+).*",'$1') -ge $TargetTime } {
        $_
    }
}
```

`-replace` operator uses regex to match a string and then replaces the matched string. `$1` is capture group one, which is the string matched by `(^\S+\s\S+)`.

- `^` is the beginning of a string.
- `\S+` matches non-white space one or more (`+`) times.
- `\s` matches a white space character.
- `.*` is 0 or more characters using a greedy match. This means match everything after the capture group.

---

You can effectively do the same as the above with a `Where-Object` condition combined with your favorite file reading method. `switch` tends to be faster if there are no memory constraints.

```
$TargetTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)
Get-Content log.log | where {
    [datetime]($_ -replace "(^\S+\s\S+).*",'$1') -ge $TargetTime
}
```

---

If the data is in ascending chronological order, you can use the `where()` method with `SkipUntil` mode.

```
$TargetTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)
(Get-Content log.log).where({
    [datetime]($_ -replace "(^\S+\s\S+).*",'$1') -ge $TargetTime
},'SkipUntil')
```

Comment: What does the "$_" inside the switch do? I can't pipe the output of switch to further filter the results, but with your last example I can.

Comment: `$_` is the current item being processed. Here it is the contents of a line. You can pipe out of the switch just surround the whole switch block with `$()` and then you can pipe that to something else.

Comment: Thanks, @AdminOfThings, with switch took 2:44 minutes, and with Get-Content took  3:14 minutes, the machine has 24 gb of memory and just went up one percentage point wen running the task, I should be worried if for some reason the memory usage increase to his limits)

Answer (score 0):

You can import the file as csv and use the DateTime feature to compare the date and time to get what you are looking for.

Example code: (Since your file wont have headers, you will have to use some names in header.

```
$expectedTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)
Import-Csv C:\temp\file.txt -Delimiter " " -Header Time, Date, field1, field2 `
    | ? { (([DateTime]$_.Date) + $_.Time) -gt $expectedTime}
```